# Where can I find information on "Quadratic Maps"?

Tags: recurrence-relations

According to Wolfram, a quadratic recurrence relation uses a second degree polynomial to express $x_{n+1}$ as a function of $x_n$.  A "quadratic map", then, is a recurrence relation:

$$x_{n+1} = a (x_n)^2 + b x_n + c$$

Aside from [Wolfram's Quadratic Map page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html), I can't seem to find much information on "Quadratic Maps".  Is there some definitive reference on the topic, or some resource/reference that explains a lot of what is known about QMs?

Comment: @TBrendle:  Yes.  I didn't have much luck.  I'm really hoping that I can some how get a general idea of what is known.  It seems that I can only get information on special cases, but maybe that is all that is known.

Comment: By a change of variable, you can reduce this to the case$$z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + d$$

Comment: Yes , then download Ultra Fractal 5 !

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like "Iterated Maps On The Interval As Dynamical Systems" by Collet and Eckmann . Additional: [http://www.amazon.com/Iterated-Interval-Dynamical-Birkh%C3%A4user-Classics/dp/0817649263#reader_0817649263](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817649263)

Perhaps also Mira-Gumowski maps,  these are generally real valued but perhaps not as simple as a quadratic map. I suggest you google the topic and view the images. Maybe that would be of interest.